Multiple Ranges in a Macro
I'm trying to randomly sort a set of ranges that contains some names using a macro, but unfortunately, it only works with one range I'm not so familiar with VBA so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
This is what I working with, and it's stopping at the sort settings comment below at .Apply.
Sub autoshuffle()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow1 As Long
    Dim lastRow2 As Long
    Dim lastRow3 As Long
    Dim lastRow4 As Long
    Dim lastRow5 As Long
    Dim sortRange1 As Range
    Dim sortRange2 As Range
    Dim sortRange3 As Range
    Dim sortRange4 As Range
    Dim sortRange5 As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names")

    ' Determine the last row with data in each column
    lastRow1 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow2 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow3 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow4 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow5 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row

    'ranges to sort
    Set sortRange1 = ws.Range("J2:M9")
    Set sortRange2 = ws.Range("N2:Q5")
    Set sortRange3 = ws.Range("R2:U14")
    Set sortRange4 = ws.Range("V2:Y13")
    Set sortRange5 = ws.Range("Z2:AC14")

    ' Clear existing sort fields
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear

    ' Add a new sort field based on each column
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("M3:M" & lastRow1), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("Q3:Q" & lastRow2), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("U3:U" & lastRow3), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("Y3:Y" & lastRow4), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("AC3:AC" & lastRow5), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    ' Sort settings
    With ws.Sort
        For i = 1 To 5
            .SetRange sortRange(i)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
    End With
End Sub

What I'm expecting is to have sorting macro to assign to a button when clicked it should shuffle the data in each range provided above.

You're missing Next i after .Apply.

I added it, but now it's giving a "compile error: Sub or Function not defined"

@AhmedEid Can you edit your question with the updated code? Also, make sure that you include the error message you get in your question.

While declared 5 variable for the five range, in the for loop you use an array.  Declare only the array, and set the ranges to the items accordingly.

Shuffle Rows of Ranges



Main

The ranges' references are created based on the last non-empty cells in their first columns, i.e., no empty cells are allowed in the ranges' first columns.
Then their rows are shuffled.

Sub AutoShuffleRangesRows()
 
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Dim RANGES_COLUMN_IDS() As Variant: RANGES_COLUMN_IDS = Array( _
        "J:M", "N:Q", "R:U", "V:Y", "Z:AC")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Names")
    
    ShuffleRangesRows ws, RANGES_COLUMN_IDS, FIRST_ROW
    
    MsgBox "Ranges' rows shuffled.", vbInformation

End Sub

Help
Sub ShuffleRangesRows( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        RangesColumnIds As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1)
 
    Dim rg As Range, Data() As Variant, n As Long, RowsCount As Long
   
    For n = LBound(RangesColumnIds) To UBound(RangesColumnIds)
        With ws.Cells(FirstRow, ws.Columns(RangesColumnIds(n)).Column)
            RowsCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column) _
                .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1 ' based on the first column!
            If RowsCount > 1 Then
                Set rg = .Resize(RowsCount).EntireRow _
                    .Columns(RangesColumnIds(n))
                Data = rg.Value
                ShuffleRows Data
                rg.Value = Data
            End If
        End With
    Next n

End Sub

Sub ShuffleRows(ByRef Data As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal SampleSize As Variant)
    
    Dim UB As Long: UB = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim Last As Long: Last = UB - 1
    
    Dim sLast As Long:
    If Not IsMissing(SampleSize) Then
        If IsNumeric(SampleSize) Then
            If SampleSize < Last Then Last = SampleSize
        End If
    End If
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    Dim Temp As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, c As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Last
        ' Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
        j = Int((UB - i + 1) * Rnd + i)
        For c = 1 To cCount
            Temp = Data(i, c): Data(i, c) = Data(j, c): Data(j, c) = Temp
        Next c
    Next i

End Sub


Initial Post: Shuffle Columns

Main

You can use numbers i.e. (13, 17) instead. You cannot use "13:15" but you can use "M:O" as an element.
If this code is in the workbook with the sheet, replace ActiveWorkbook with ThisWorkbook.

Sub AutoShuffleColumns()
    
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Dim COLUMN_IDS() As Variant: COLUMN_IDS = Array( _
        "M", "Q", "U", "Y", "AC")

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Names")
    
    ShuffleWorksheetColumnsEnd ws, COLUMN_IDS, FIRST_ROW
    
    MsgBox "Columns shuffled.", vbInformation

End Sub

Help
Sub ShuffleWorksheetColumnsEnd( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ColumnIds As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1)
 
    Dim rrg As Range, crg As Range, cell As Range, Data() As Variant
    Dim n As Long, RowsCount As Long
    
    For n = LBound(ColumnIds) To UBound(ColumnIds)
        Set rrg = ws.Rows(FirstRow).Columns(ColumnIds(n))
        For Each cell In rrg.Cells
            RowsCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, cell.Column) _
                .End(xlUp).Row - FirstRow + 1
            If RowsCount > 1 Then
                Set crg = cell.Resize(RowsCount)
                Data = crg.Value
                ShuffleColumn Data
                crg.Value = Data
            End If
        Next cell
    Next n

End Sub

Sub ShuffleColumn(ByRef Data As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Long = 1, _
        Optional ByVal SampleSize As Variant)
    
    Dim UB As Long: UB = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim Last As Long: Last = UB - 1
    
    Dim sLast As Long:
    If Not IsMissing(SampleSize) Then
        If IsNumeric(SampleSize) Then
            If SampleSize < Last Then Last = SampleSize
        End If
    End If
    
    Dim Temp As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Last
        ' Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
        j = Int((UB - i + 1) * Rnd + i)
        Temp = Data(i, ColumnIndex)
        Data(i, ColumnIndex) = Data(j, ColumnIndex)
        Data(j, ColumnIndex) = Temp
    Next i

End Sub


You were on the right track. With the use of arrays and an adjustment to your logic, your routine should look like this. I have tested this and it works fine:
Option Explicit

Sub autoshuffle()

  Dim ws                As Worksheet
  Dim i                 As Integer
  Dim lastRow(1 To 5)   As Long
  Dim sortRange(1 To 5) As Range
  Dim arrCol(1 To 5)    As String

  Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names")

  ' Sort columns
  arrCol(1) = "M3:M"
  arrCol(2) = "Q3:Q"
  arrCol(3) = "U3:U"
  arrCol(4) = "Y3:Y"
  arrCol(5) = "AC3:AC"

  With ws

    ' Determine the last row with data in each column
    lastRow(1) = .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow(2) = .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow(3) = .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow(4) = .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow(5) = .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row

    'ranges to sort
    Set sortRange(1) = .Range("J2:M9")
    Set sortRange(2) = .Range("N2:Q5")
    Set sortRange(3) = .Range("R2:U14")
    Set sortRange(4) = .Range("V2:Y13")
    Set sortRange(5) = .Range("Z2:AC14")

    ' Perform all the sorts
    With .Sort

      For i = 1 To 5

        ' Clear existing sort fields
        .SortFields.Clear

        ' Add a new sort field based on each column
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range(arrCol(i) & lastRow(i)), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .SetRange sortRange(i)
            
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

      Next

    End With
  End With

End Sub

I would also highly recommend that you include Option Explicit as the first line in EVERY module. Option Explicit forces explicit declaration of all variables in that module and will highlight misspelled or undeclared variables at compile time.  You can have this done automatically every time you create a module by going to Tools -> Options in the VB Editor. Then on the Editor tab, enable the Require Variable Declaration option.
